# R: Fill NA values with ascending numbers

Tags: r, dplyr, fill

With `R` I would like to fill a column of mostly NA values with ascending/descending numbers (integers), but relative to a row with value 0.  The numbering should be grouped by Subject (1st Column). This sounds confusing, so please look at the example.
The data looks like this (Column_3 is current and Column_4 is the goal):

| Subject | Visit | Column_3 | Column_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Visit 1 | NA | -2 |
| 001 | Visit 2 | NA | -1 |
| 001 | Visit 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 001 | Visit 4 | NA | 1 |
| 001 | Visit 5 | NA | 2 |
| 002 | Visit 1 | NA | -1 |
| 002 | Visit 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 002 | Visit 3 | NA | 1 |
| 002 | Visit 4 | NA | 2 |
| 002 | Visit 5 | NA | 3 |
| 003 | Visit 1 | NA | -3 |
| 003 | Visit 2 | NA | -2 |
| 003 | Visit 3 | NA | -1 |
| 003 | Visit 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 003 | Visit 5 | NA | 1 |

So all subjects have a certain number of visits (1-5) and a certain visit  indicated by the 0 (different for each subject) in Column 3. In Column 4 I would like to have the numbers in ascending order in reference to the visit indicated by the 0.

Currently I try to make a pipe with `dplyr`:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(Subject) %>%
     mutate(
    column 4 = lag(Column_3, 1),
    code here
    ) %>%
    ungroup()
```

I'm trying to make use of `fill()` and `lag()` and `lead()`, but I don't know how to use these efficiently in this case (unfortunately I have not found an "inefficient" approach either).

Suggestions are welcome!

Comment: You would get more help if you would post the output of `dput( head( df, 15 ) )` so that people can work with your data instead of reconstructing them, possibly making wrong assumptions

Answer (score 3):

Slightly different option:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  mutate(column_4 = row_number() - row_number()[!is.na(column_3 == 0)]) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  group_by(Subject) |>
  mutate(Column_4 = row_number() - which(Column_3 == 0))

+ # A tibble: 15 × 4
# Groups:   Subject [3]
   Subject Visit   Column_3 Column_4
   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>       <int>
 1 001     Visit 1 NA             -2
 2 001     Visit 2 NA             -1
 3 001     Visit 3 0               0
 4 001     Visit 4 NA              1
 5 001     Visit 5 NA              2
 6 002     Visit 1 NA             -1
 7 002     Visit 2 0               0
 8 002     Visit 3 NA              1
 9 002     Visit 4 NA              2
10 002     Visit 5 NA              3
11 003     Visit 1 NA             -3
12 003     Visit 2 NA             -2
13 003     Visit 3 NA             -1
14 003     Visit 4 0               0
15 003     Visit 5 NA              1
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks clean and straight forward. On first tries I do get an error that seems to be related to the grouping/ungrouping : `"Column_4" must be size 7 or 1, not 0.`

Comment: @Elyakim I am sorry but I need an exact copy of your data to figure out. Try to append the output of `dput(df)` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr) 

df <- structure(list(Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Visit = c("Visit 1", "Visit 2", "Visit 3", 
"Visit 4", "Visit 5", "Visit 1", "Visit 2", "Visit 3", "Visit 4", 
"Visit 5", "Visit 1", "Visit 2", "Visit 3", "Visit 4", "Visit 5"
), Column_3 = c(NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0L, NA), Column_4 = c(-2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, -3L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))

df %>% 
  group_by(Subject) %>% 
  mutate(Column_5 = row_number() * (Column_3 == 0), 
         Column_5 = row_number() - max(Column_5, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  ungroup

#> # A tibble: 15 × 5
#>    Subject Visit   Column_3 Column_4 Column_5
#>      <int> <chr>      <int>    <int>    <int>
#>  1       1 Visit 1       NA       -2       -2
#>  2       1 Visit 2       NA       -1       -1
#>  3       1 Visit 3        0        0        0
#>  4       1 Visit 4       NA        1        1
#>  5       1 Visit 5       NA        2        2
#>  6       2 Visit 1       NA       -1       -1
#>  7       2 Visit 2        0        0        0
#>  8       2 Visit 3       NA        1        1
#>  9       2 Visit 4       NA        2        2
#> 10       2 Visit 5       NA        3        3
#> 11       3 Visit 1       NA       -3       -3
#> 12       3 Visit 2       NA       -2       -2
#> 13       3 Visit 3       NA       -1       -1
#> 14       3 Visit 4        0        0        0
#> 15       3 Visit 5       NA        1        1
```